# How to get new Array values? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random, 2d, reset

So I've made a function with a 2D-array that's 5x5. Inside values are being randomed between five different values and placed in the array.
I then call upon this function in my main();. However, the issue is that when I call the function of the array, the results are always the same. So it seems like the array isn't being reseted or getting new random values every time I run the function.

How could this be solved? I want the array to get new values every time I run the function so that every time I call upon the function from main(); there will be new values in the array,

My complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime> 

using namespace std;


char array2D[5][5];

int roll(){

srand (time(0)); 

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<5; y++){
            array2D[x][y] = "ABCDE"[rand() % 5];
        }
    }

    for (int x=0; x<5; x++){  
        for (int y=0; y<5; y++){ 
            cout << array2D[x][y]; 
        }
    cout << endl;  
    }

        cout << endl;  


    return 0; 

}




int main()
{
roll();
roll();
roll();

return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to call srand() at the beginning of main()

Comment: perhaps the seed does not have chance to change your function is too fast.

Comment: @PatrickSweigl Thanks a bunch and how silly of me to miss that. I almost feel ashamed. 
Putting "srand (time(0));" in the top of the main(); solved the issue. Is this "one of the correct ways" of doing what I want to do? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `srand (time(0));` to the main function.

`time(0)` is a number of seconds, so unless the call goes over a second boundary, it will reset to the same value.

Comment: Yes I forgot about the placement of "srand (time(0));".
It all seems to work like it should now, moving it to main();
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `srand` more than once (unless you actually WANT to repeat some random numbers). In your case, I suspect the chances of running all `roll` functions within the same second is quite high, so they would all give the same random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

If you call the function several times during a single second, then yes the result will most definitely be the same as you set the random number seed to the same value.

You should only set the seed *once*, preferably as early as possible in the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of granularity of system timer (`time(0)`). As I remember, `time(0)` has new value every second. But all three runs of your function fit in one second, so timer has no time to receive new value.

If you want to have new random values each time function runs, just move your `stand(time(0))` to the beginning of your `main` function